# How can I create and use aggregate field with TADODataset?

Tags: delphi, ado

I can create a new aggregate field (TAggregateField ) with TADODataset in design mode, 
With expression "Sum(MyPrice)" (MyPrice is a field in this data set).

but this field does not display anything in the binded DBText control (it is simply empty).

Can TAggregateField even be used with TADODataset? (all examples I have seen were related to TClientDataSet)

Comment: You can use `TAggregateField` with ADO datasets, but you'll get always NULL values because ADO dataset classes do not implement the `GetAggregateValue` method. So no, there is no support for it.

Comment: @MartynA, the new field type should be "Data" (not calculated or lookup). I'm aware of server aggregation. problem is that any changes made to the dataset on the client, needs to refresh/requery the dataset from the server.

Comment: @TLama, thank you! this is the asnwer (GetAggregateValue is not implimented).

Comment: @TLama, can you make it an answer please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of the ADO dataset based components shipped with Delphi supports aggregate fields. They would have to implement aggregate support methods (such as e.g. [`GetAggregateValue`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.GetAggregateValue)) of the [`TDataSet`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/Data.DB.TDataSet) ancestor.

To your question, yes, you can use [`TAggregateField`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/Data.DB.TAggregateField) with shipped ADO components (there's nothing what would restrict you) but it's useless because such field will always return `NULL` value due to missing [`GetAggregateValue`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.GetAggregateValue) method implementation in ADO components.